# Cifrado de archivo con gpg y clave publica

Tags: php, gpg

Tengo el siguiente comando para encriptar archivos mediante `gpg` en linux usando una clave publica:

```
 gpg --output archivo_salida.txt.gpg --encrypt --recipient xxx@xxx.org archivo.txt
```

El comando funciona con la unica salvedad que para ejecutarse me pide una confirmación Y/N

Mi consulta es como podria lograr que se ejectura la acción sin pasar por la pregunta de confirmación.

Comment: ¿Por que agregaste la etiqueta PHP?

Comment: La documentación de GnuPG no indica que este comando muestre una confirmación. Lo estás usando directamente en la terminal? La opción simple es hacer algo como `echo 'Y' | gpg ...` y que reciba el **Y**, je.

Comment: A primera vista el comando no incluye la opción se ejecutarse sin pedir confirmación: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/gpg.htm

Comment: @Orici de hecho en lo que enlazas mencionan un `--yes` y un `--quiet` que pueden servir ;)